# How do I add a unique ID column to my Foundry Rules output?

Tags: palantir-foundry

When setting up the Foundry Rules workflow, I can define the columns of the output dataset. Is there a way to have a column that has a unique ID for the records created through the Foundry Rules application? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a python transform (e.g. in a code repository) that takes in the output dataset of your Foundry Rules workflow as an input, and outputs a dataset that has an additional column with a unique ID.

1. The following [article](https://pythonisrad.medium.com/uuids-in-pyspark-53fd3935d093) explains how you could generate a unique ID (UUID) column in PySpark.
2. You can then use the output dataset of the transform for your downstream workflows e.g. as the backing dataset for an object type.